# What does word "jibi" means?

Tags: vocabulary, slang

I guess it's a slang word, so I can not find it in a dictionary.

Comment: I've never encountered it before; I imagine it's very localized. UrbanDictionary does have an entry for [*jibi*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jibi) (as a synonym for *cool*), but it only has 13 votes, so it seems like it's just someone's private language. Can you share the context or contexts in which you've encountered it? Ideally with surrounding language or text.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no context available

Comment: Can you at least use it in a sentence as how you heard it?

Comment: @Antonio You heard or read it somewhere. Where? What else was said or read at the time? You believe it to be a word. Why? What lead you to ask this question? In other words: there certainly is context. Share it.

Comment: I heard it from an old Indian. He was talking about spirits. I have not understood what he told

Comment: @Antonio If you are referring to an Indian from India (versus a Native American), you might be meaning a [Jinn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn). The singular versions include an "I" on the end.

Comment: No, I mean Native American

Answer (score 2):

Are you possibly mishearing "[chibi](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chibi)"? (Urban Dict.)

(I don't have enough rep to comment, or I would have :/ )

Answer (score 0):

There is a nautical term in English, but it is spelled as *jib*.

And it means A triangular stay-sail stretching from the outer end of the jib-boom to the fore-topmast head in large ships, and from the bowsprit to the mast-head in smaller craft.

Comment: But "jib" is not "jibi".

Comment: That is a gratuitous comment:  I checked with the Historical Dictionary of American Slang, (5-Volume Random House Ed.), I checked with  Dictionary of American Regional English, (Harvard - Bellknap, Cassidy editor) and I checked with the Chapman's Sailors Lexicon, and the word does not exist, and the inquirer does not know the context, and I forwarded an educated guess. Most of the questions asked are very vaguely defined, in addition to being quite proficient in English ( I am on two Western and 2 Eastern languages) one has to be quite a good estimator of what the inquirers' background is!

Comment: It was certainly not meant to be gratuitous, Abe, but OPs asking poor questions who are conscientiously prodded by the community to provide more information, should either provide that information or as we're doing here...leave it to the community to close the question.  What isn't particularly useful is to have answers based on incomplete question information.  Sometimes it's better to not answer a question than to hazard a guess at what the OP is asking - although I think we all get sucked into doing that occasionally. At least now I know what a "jib" is!   :-)

Comment: Rather than posting an answer merely based on guessing at what the question is supposed to be, if the questioner has supplied no supporting evidence for your supposition you should post it as a comment. Otherwise, it is likely that your answer will be deleted.